# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to iterate over material index using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/how-to-iterate-over-material-index-using-python)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to select even/odd keyframes with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/how-to-select-even-odd-keyframes-with-python)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I render an edge only mesh as solid lines?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-can-i-render-an-edge-only-mesh-as-solid-lines)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it possible to generate an image based on edges and corners?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3370/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-image-based-on-edges-and-corners)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Capture a partial screenshot in the BGE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3166/capture-a-partial-screenshot-in-the-bge)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Digits of precision of vertices coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/digits-of-precision-of-vertices-coordinates)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a way to overlay two similar UV islands with identical vertex count?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-two-similar-uv-islands-with-identical-vertex-count)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Stream of mist between objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/stream-of-mist-between-objects)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to set up custom controls - Pan using Mouse 4 + MMB](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/how-to-set-up-custom-controls-pan-using-mouse-4-mmb)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---